# QuickBlox Online/Offline issues in iOS

Tags: ios, quickblox

I've tried `QuickBlox` Documentation method but last request time is all the time constant, Actually it should be updated when connected user do any activity with Quick blox like chat with some one.
but, it's remain same.(it give the time when user login only).
so how it will be updated on each request?
I tried the following code.

```
[QBACCESS fetchUserDetailsWithID:userID withCompeltionHandler:^(QBUUser *userDetails,BOOL status){
    if(status){
        QBUUser *user = userDetails;
        NSInteger currentTimeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSInteger userLastRequestAtTimeInterval   = [[user lastRequestAt] timeIntervalSince1970];
        // if user didn't do anything last 1 minute (60 seconds)
        if((currentTimeInterval - userLastRequestAtTimeInterval) > 60){
        //means user is offline
        }
        else{
        //user is online
        }
    }
}];
```

Here in all the cases it show offline because my [user lastRequestAt]is same all the time when user login.
So, it's not give real time online/offline. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I found that only by Subscription state, we can achieve  real time online/offline using QuickBlox.

There are four Subscription State.

1. QBPresenseSubscriptionStateNone
2. QBPresenseSubscriptionStateTo
3. QBPresenseSubscriptionStateFrom
4. QBPresenseSubscriptionStateBoth

For checking realtime online/offile we need to send request to opponent(other) user, if opponent user accept their request means QBPresenseSubscriptionStateBoth, then both will know about each other and following delegate method will be called,

```
- (void)chatContactListDidChange:(QBContactList *)contactList{

}

- (void)chatDidReceiveContactItemActivity:(NSUInteger)userID 
                                 isOnline:(BOOL)isOnline
                                   status:(NSString *)status{

    //here we check offline/online of particular user using ID.
}
```

For more details please go through: [Contact List](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Contact_list).